# How to get original image from Filters

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I have an image with filters, now I want to go back to the original image on click of a button.

not sure if I need to make a constance for it

```
@IBAction func Blur(_ sender: Any) {
    let inputImg = UIimage.image!

    let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: inputImg)

    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
    blurFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    blurFilter.setValue(8, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    if let output = blurFilter.outputImage{
        if let ciImg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent){
            UIimage.image = UIImage(cgImage: ciImg)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you wish to revert to `inputimg` or `inputCIImage`? Consider only this - both variables have a "variable scope" of existing **only** inside `@IBAction func Blur`. If you wish to access either of those variables, you *must* have them exist to be accessible outside of the function. so yes, you *need* to make a constant for it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just store the original image in your ViewController, and apply a filer depending on a state?

I would assume that what you call `UIImage` is a `UIImageView` tell me if I am wrong.

```
let inputImg = // Your original image
let isBlured = false

@IBAction func didClickButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if isBlured {
        myUIImageView.image = inputImg // original image 
        isBlured = false 
    } else {

        let inputCIImage = CIImage(image: inputImg)
        let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
        blurFilter.setValue(inputCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter.setValue(8, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)

        if let output = blurFilter.outputImage{
            if let ciImg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent){
                myUIImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: ciImg)
                isBlured = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```